# Custom fonts in google maps with flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-api-3

I am working with flutter and google maps.
The text fonts in google maps are not the ones in my app.
Is there a way to let google maps use my custom fonts?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean in the default labels? Or on your own custom markers?

Comment: I mean the whole style. At least the roads. Featuretype, elementtype, stylers

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately, changing the font is not possible currently and what you can change is just the `Text fill color` and the `Text stroke color`. ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/cloud-customization/taxonomy#what_you_can_style_for_each_map_feature